# Customise the WooCommerce Product Widget

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hyperlink, woocommerce

I need to redirect the user to a specific page by placing a hyperlink just before a closing `</ul>` tag (which is within a *WordPress* sidebar widget).

An example of what I am trying to achieve can be found below, using the *WooCommerce Products* widget which has been slightly modified to include an additional *Specials* hyperlink:

[image]

---

I am using the *WooCommerce 2.9.1* plugin, and believe that the file I need to modify is the
`class-widgets-products.php` file.  This file is made up with the following code - http://pastebin.com/vgpSqa6X.

---

On line `178` I have placed the following, which will display a hyperlink taking the user to a *Specials* page on the website:

```
echo '<a href="'. get_site_url().'/specials/" class="go-to">&#187; Specials</a>';
```

---

However, with this particular widget, it creates three separate instances and this will apply the hyperlink to *All Products*, *Featured Products* and *On-sale Products*.

[image]

---

How can I create **separate hyperlinks** that will apply to the widget, depending on which option has been selected in the admin menu?

For example, if the *Featured Products* option has been selected, it will output a *Featured Products* hyperlink at the bottom, and if the *On-sale* option has been selected, it will output a *Specials* hyperlink at the bottom.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to lie in :

```
$this->settings->show->options
```

or :

```
$this->settings['show']['options']
```

...as the code you have pasted suggests.

Just evaluate this value with if's (or [switches](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.switch.php), whatever you feel comfortable with) :

```
if ($this->settings['show']['options'] == "this_particular_kind")
{
   $link_at_the_bottom = '<a href="'. get_site_url().'/this_particular_kind/" class="go-to">&#187; This Particular Kind</a>';
}
...
```